# Init pd.Series from list of fields

Tags: pandas, series

I wonder that

```
columns=['A','B','C']
pd.Series(columns=columns)
```

yield

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

while

`pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)`

works.

Is there such init function from a list of columns in `pd.Series`?

---

I know that this can be done with a dict in the middle:

```
columns=['A','B','C']
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(columns)
my_series = pd.Series(my_dict)
```

..But I think it would be nice to have it as `pd.Series(colums=columns)`directly.

Comment: A series only has one column.  You can loop through and generate multiple series and name them.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BrianPreslopsky Added some example over `dict` to explain the purpose. I like to init a Series with the same variables as the DataFrame which the data is getting appended later on.

Comment: except your `my_series` doesn't have columns....it set the index to your series to the keys of the dict. You can see for yourself with `my_series.index`